# Problems understanding sequential Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have been examining a code example and I cannot understand what is happening, I have tried to understand easier examples and get them but at this one I am getting stuck:

```
seq([X, X | Xs]) -> [X | seq(Xs)];
seq([X, Y | Xs]) -> [X, Y | seq(Xs)];
seq(_) -> [].
```

When I run it in the shell with [1,1,1,2,2,2,3] I get [1,1,2,2]. I have been trying to understand the steps by writing it on paper but I got stuck halfway trough.

I would appreciate all answers explaining me the steps happening here! :)
/Eri.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to get [1,2,3] as the output? Please specify the expected result.

Comment: I don't want to get any specific output, I just want to understand how sequential erlang works, the code I presented above is a example of it. When I run it with  [1,1,1,2,2,2,3] I get [1,1,2,2], I just want to know how it comes I get [1,1,2,2] in order to learn how the steps are performed. Therefore I want somebody to explain me the steps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so we start with a list of `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3]`.

On the first call to `seq`, erlang will match the first two elements `1` and `1` to the first "clause" of `seq` - `seq([X, X | Xs])`.
This will initialize the list that will become the final return value, `[1, seq(Xs)]`.  Now at this point `Xs` will be bound to the value `[1,2,2,2,3]`. If you're wondering why there aren't two 1's at the beginning of the Xs list it's because we matched/bound two of them on `[X, X | Xs]`.

**Return value** = `[1 | ?]`  (? is the remaining recursion to be evaluated)
**Xs** = `[1,2,2,2,3]`

On the second call to `seq`, erlang will match the first two elements of the input list `1` and `2` to the second clause `seq([X, Y | Xs])`.  We then "return" the list [X, Y] or [1, 2] from this run, and call the next iteration with Xs = [2,2,3].

**Return value** = `[1 | [1, 2 | ?]]`  <- See how recursion nests the lists? 
**Xs** = `[2,2,3]`

On the third call, the first two elements are the same again, so erlang runs the first clause again.  `seq([X, X | Xs]) -> [X | seq(Xs)]`.  We return a single `2` value as part of the evaluation, and call `seq([3])`.

**Return value** = `[1 | [1, 2 | [2 | ?]]]`  
**Xs** = `[3]`

At last, the final case.  Our list of [3] doesn't match `[X, X | Xs]` nor `[X, Y, Xs]`, so erlang will run our catch-all: `seq(_) -> [].` `_` will match anything, and not bind the value to any local variables, so all we do here is return an empty list `[]`.

Our final return value then is:  `[1 | [1, 2 | [2 | []]]]`.  If you evaluate this into your erl repl, you'll see it's the same as the list `[1,1,2,2]`, the later is syntactic sugar for the former.

Comment: Many many thanks!! You explained it very well and I am now understanding how it goes, awesome!!!

Answer (score 4):

Tracing can help you a little bit:

```
1> dbg:tracer().
{ok,<0.35.0>}
2> dbg:p(self(), [c]).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,1}]}
3> dbg:tpl({test, seq, 1}, [{'_',[],[{return_trace}]}]).
{ok,[{matched,nonode@nohost,1},{saved,1}]}
4> test:seq([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]).
(<0.33.0>) call test:seq([1,1,1,2,2,2,3])
(<0.33.0>) call test:seq([1,2,2,2,3])
(<0.33.0>) call test:seq([2,2,3])
(<0.33.0>) call test:seq([3])
(<0.33.0>) returned from test:seq/1 -> []
(<0.33.0>) returned from test:seq/1 -> [2]
(<0.33.0>) returned from test:seq/1 -> [1,2,2]
(<0.33.0>) returned from test:seq/1 -> [1,1,2,2]
[1,1,2,2]
```

Comment: If the function was tail-recursive, it would be even more helpful because the values produced would be visible in the trace too.